# Prove that total sum of squares is given by $y^TB^TBy$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics

Given an $n \times 1$ vector of outputs $y$, how does one prove that the total sum of squares $$S_\text{tot}=y^TB^TBy$$ where $B=(I-\vec1(\vec1^T\vec{1})^{-1}\vec{1}^T)$

Further, how does one show that $B$ is symmetric and idempotent?

Note: $\vec{1}$ is the vector of ones and $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Do you know that $(AB)^T$ (with $A$ on the left and $B$ on the right) is equal to $B^T A^T$ (with $B^T$ on the left and $A^T$ on the right)? And that $(C^{-1})^T = (C^T)^{-1}$? That's most of the task of proving that it's symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For $B$ you have $\left(\vec1^T\vec{1}\right)$ being the $1 \times 1$ matrix with value $n$,
- so  $\vec1\left(\vec1^T\vec{1}\right)^{-1}\vec{1}^T$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with each element value $\frac{1}{n}$
- so $B=I-\vec1\left(\vec1^T\vec{1}\right)^{-1}\vec{1}^T$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with leading diagonal values $1-\frac1n$ and other values $-\frac{1}n$.  This is obviously symmetric
- To show it is idempotent, you want $B^2=B$ and this is a consequence of $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2+(n-1)\left(-\frac{1}n\right)^2 =1-\frac1n$ and of  $2\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(-\frac{1}n\right)+(n-2)\left(-\frac{1}n\right)^2 =-\frac{1}n$.
- So $B^TB=B^2=B$
- and thus $\vec y^TB^TB\vec y = \vec y^T B\vec y = \vec y^T I \vec y -\vec y^T\vec1\left(\vec1^T\vec{1}\right)^{-1}\vec{1}^T \vec y$
- where $\vec y^T I \vec y = \sum_i y_i^2$
- and $\vec y^T\vec1\left(\vec1^T\vec{1}\right)^{-1}\vec{1}^T \vec y = \frac1n \sum_j\sum_k  y_j y_k = \frac1n \left(\sum_j  y_j\right)^2 = n \bar y^2$
- so $\vec y^TB^TB\vec y = \sum_i y_i^2 - n \bar y^2 = \sum_i \left(y_i^2 -  \bar y^2\right)= \sum_i \left(y_i - \bar y\right)^2$